# How to make conditional disabled attribute on button in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[SOLVED]
I want button to be disabled based on condition.

This does not compile:

```
<button aura:id="toggleButton" {!if(..., 'disabled', '')}>
```

This is always disabled

```
<button aura:id="toggleButton" disabled="{!if(..., 'true', 'false')}">
```

This throws runtime error:

```
component.find("toggleButton").set("v.disabled", true);
```

> Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'disabled' of
>   component 'markup://aura:html {54:1252;a} {toggleButton}' is not
>   visible to 'markup://c:TreeNode {50:1252;a}'.

Remark: I want to have tree chevron icon disabled, so I want to utilise SLDS css rules.
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/?variant=base#react-target
[image]

Comment: And how are you passing the unique id to button elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

standard html `button` is disabled when `disabled` exists with any value.
You can render two types of buttons based on condition

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isDisabled}">
    <button aura:id="toggleButton" disabled/>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <button aura:id="toggleButton"/>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

another option is to replace standard html `<button/>` with `<ui:button>` or `<lightning:button>`, then the following works:

```
component.find("toggleButton").set("v.disabled", true);
```

Comment: cannot use lightning:button because they look differently (with borders etc)